# Are those operations equivalent?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm refactoring some code and I've stumbled upon a passage like this.

```
if (a > 1.0)
  a = 1.0;
else if (a < -1.0)
  a = -1.0;
```

According to the guidelines we've got, I should refactor it into something like this.

```
if (Math.Abs(a) > 1.0)
  a = a < 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0;
```

The refactorization is, of course, only allowed if that doesn't change the logic of the statement. I've though it through and didn't see any deviations or any discrepancies. I've also wrote and ran a bunch of tests, really trying to pinpoint the tricky and edgy cases. Everything seems to be fine.

Then, a colleague at work took a peek at it and suggested in a very poisonous tone that there's something itchy there. He was supposed to reveal the big secret the day after but then he got sick and now he's on vacation.

I've been gazing at the lines for a few days now. I've slept on it. I've tried all the tricks in my sleeve. Nothing! So either I'm just not skilled to see it or he's just an ass playing nasty tricks. I need help determining.

Comment: Maybe he just needed to see your test results, heh.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs(v=vs.110).aspx) depends on the data type. `double` for example will take `double.NegativeInfinity` and return `double.PositiveInfinity`, which makes sense. But with `int32` there's no positive value of its MinValue, so that particular overload will [throw an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx(v=vs.110).aspx) on `int32.MinValue`, whereas your original code would instead set it to `-1` instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @Quantic The type of `a` must be a double, otherwise the assignment `a = 1.0` would fail to compile.

Comment: Personally I prefer the un-refactored code. To me it is much quicker to see the intent than the refactored version.

Comment: @Quantic This should really be an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes they are the same. **Update**: but not with the case `Int.MinValue` \ `Long.MinValue` etc, as `Math.Abs` would thrown an `OverflowException` - thanks @SledgeHammer/@Quantic! - so that could be the catch.

"Proof" that the methods are the same (minus the overflow)

```
if (Math.Abs(a) > 1.0)
  a = a < 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0;
```

Is the same as: (`?:` to `if`)

```
if (Math.Abs(a) > 1.0)
{
    if (a < 0)
    {
        a = -1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 1.0;
    }
}
```

and this is the same as: (written out `Math.Abs`)

```
if (a > 1.0 || a < -1.0)
{
    if (a < 0)
    {
        a = -1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 1.0;
    }
}
```

and this is the same as: (translated `||` to `if`-`else if`)

```
if (a > 1.0)
{
    if (a < 0)
    {
        a = -1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 1.0;
    }
}
else if (a < -1.0)
{
    if (a < 0)
    {
        a = -1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 1.0;
    }
}
```

removing dead code:

```
if (a > 1.0)
{
    if (a >= 0) //else
    {
        a = 1.0;
    }
}
else if (a < -1.0)
{
    if (a < 0)
    {
        a = -1.0;
    }
}
```

and now with removing the unneeded (inner) `if`s:

```
if (a > 1.0)
{
    a = 1.0;
}
else if (a < -1.0)
{
   a = -1.0;
}
```

Done :)

PS: for readability if prefer:

```
if (a > 1.0)
  a = 1.0;
else if (a < -1.0)
  a = -1.0;
```

### Update: Math.Abs

from `Math.Abs(a) > 1.0` to `a > 1.0 || a < -1.0`

```
Math.Abs(a) > 1.0
```

`Math.Abs(a)` is equivalent to  (see [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,1c02e346de90ef5a))

```
a >= 0 ? a : -a
```

Same as

```
if (a >= 0)
{
    return a;
}
else
{
    return -a;
}
```

So added the condition:

```
if (a >= 0)
{
    return a > 1.0;
}
else
{

    return (-a) > 1.0;
}
```

rewrite condition:

```
if (a >= 0)
{
    return a > 1.0;
}
else
{
    return a < -1.0;
}
```

else is never true for `(a >= 0)`, so

```
a > 1.0 || a < -1.0
```

Comment: I think any potential difference in this question would hidden in the details of `Math.Abs`. There's already a case in the comments where the code does not behave exactly the same. Assuming you can replace `Math.Abs(a) > 1.0` with `a > 1.0 || a < -1.0` mostly defeats the question, from my point of view.

Comment: Agree the ` throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_NegateTwosCompNum"));` is a problem here

Comment: @SledgeHammer your statement isn't true when using a `long` ;) (but then it's another minvalue issue)

Answer (score 1):

[Julian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862530/6179296) shows why they are the same conceptually, so I'll look deep inside.

I wrote a small test program and then viewed the disassembly (Visual Studio 2012)

```
class Program
{
    static void A(double a)
    {
        if (a > 1.0)
            a = 1.0;
        else if (a < -1.0)
            a = -1.0;
    }

    static void B(double a)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(a) > 1.0)
            a = a < 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A(-1.17);
        B(-1.17);
    }
}
```

**Results for A**

```
            if (a > 1.0)
0000002b  fld         qword ptr [ebp+8] 
0000002e  fld1 
00000030  fcomip      st,st(1) 
00000032  fstp        st(0) 
00000034  jp          0000003A 
00000036  jb          0000003E 
00000038  jmp         0000003A 
0000003a  xor         eax,eax 
0000003c  jmp         00000043 
0000003e  mov         eax,1 
00000043  test        eax,eax 
00000045  sete        al 
00000048  movzx       eax,al 
0000004b  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],eax 
0000004e  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],0 
00000052  jne         0000005C 
                a = 1.0;
00000054  fld1 
00000056  fstp        qword ptr [ebp+8] 
00000059  nop 
0000005a  jmp         00000092 
            else if (a < -1.0)
0000005c  fld         qword ptr [ebp+8] 
0000005f  fld         dword ptr ds:[001D2F50h] 
00000065  fcomip      st,st(1) 
00000067  fstp        st(0) 
00000069  jp          0000006F 
0000006b  ja          00000073 
0000006d  jmp         0000006F 
0000006f  xor         eax,eax 
00000071  jmp         00000078 
00000073  mov         eax,1 
00000078  test        eax,eax 
0000007a  sete        al 
0000007d  movzx       eax,al 
00000080  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],eax 
00000083  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],0 
00000087  jne         00000092 
                a = -1.0;
00000089  fld         dword ptr ds:[001D2F58h] 
0000008f  fstp        qword ptr [ebp+8]
```

Total: 38 instructions

**Results for B**

```
            if (Math.Abs(a) > 1.0)
0000002b  fld         qword ptr [ebp+8] 
0000002e  sub         esp,8 
00000031  fstp        qword ptr [esp] 
00000034  call        749B481F 
00000039  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-44h] 
0000003c  fld         qword ptr [ebp-44h] 
0000003f  fld1 
00000041  fcomip      st,st(1) 
00000043  fstp        st(0) 
00000045  jp          0000004B 
00000047  jb          0000004F 
00000049  jmp         0000004B 
0000004b  xor         eax,eax 
0000004d  jmp         00000054 
0000004f  mov         eax,1 
00000054  test        eax,eax 
00000056  sete        al 
00000059  movzx       eax,al 
0000005c  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],eax 
0000005f  cmp         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],0 
00000063  jne         0000008A 
                a = a < 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0;
00000065  fld         qword ptr [ebp+8] 
00000068  fldz 
0000006a  fcomip      st,st(1) 
0000006c  fstp        st(0) 
0000006e  jp          00000072 
00000070  ja          0000007A 
00000072  nop 
00000073  fld1 
00000075  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
00000078  jmp         00000083 
0000007a  fld         dword ptr ds:[001D3008h] 
00000080  fstp        qword ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
00000083  nop 
00000084  fld         qword ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
00000087  fstp        qword ptr [ebp+8]
```

Total: 36 instructions + function call to Math.Abs

**Result:**
The first one is probably a tiny bit faster, but they are so close in size it is hard to imagine a situation where performance is actually seriously impacted by using one over the other.  I personally agree with the comments that your original version is conceptually easier to understand.

**Edit** It seems, thanks to other comments above, that the main difference is whether exceptions can be thrown from `Math.Abs` or swallowed by your original version.  It looks like you're using `double` though, and the docs make [no mention of exceptions on the `double` version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2yzeea2(v=vs.110).aspx) like [they do for the `int` version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk4666yx(v=vs.110).aspx).  I still support your original version.

Comment: Nice approach!  Now let's hope other compiler won't fail us :P

Comment: @SledgeHammer that is why I added "+ function call to Math.Abs", and still gave the winner to the first version, despite being 2 instructions longer.  The function call is >2 instructions either way, plus more if the second one gets called.  The first is shorter regardless.  Plus, the code in your answer uses the `int` overload.  The OP is using `double`.  [This page](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,36d8f3b3bd14bad6) shows the source for the `double` and `int` versions.  The `int` version shows mostly as you describe, but I can't see the source for `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
a = Math.Min(Math.Abs(a), 1.0) * Math.Sign(a);
```

Assuming you have [FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) support for the `Math` operations, the above may execute more quickly due to the [clean pipeline](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/risc/pipelining/) and better [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor)... since there are no branches, since we have removed all the `if` statements.  This is all hardware dependent, of course, and you will not be able to see reduction in code size from inspecting the IL.  You just need to "know" this is sort of better.  In certain circumstances.

Mention this to your instructor for extra credit :)

Comment: This solution is not correct, use `Math.Min` instead of `Math.Max`